# Encrypt and Decrypt String in C# .net 3.5

Tags: c#, encryption

I know there are several questions relating to this, however most answers provide solutions for .net 4.0 and above. For my uses I have to target .net 3.5. I am looking to simply encrypt and decrypt a string for storage in a file, the text in question is not sensitive user/personal information.

The code I have so far is

```
public static string EncryptString(this string text)
{
    string result = null;
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        byte [] plaintextBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes ( text );
        SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm = DES.Create ();
        symmetricAlgorithm.Key = new byte [8] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream ();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream ( memoryStream, symmetricAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor (), CryptoStreamMode.Write );
        cryptoStream.Write ( plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length );
        result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString ( memoryStream.ToArray () );
        }
    return result;
}
```

and

```
public static string DecryptString(this string text)
{
    string result = null;
    if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty ( text ) )
    {
        byte [] encryptedBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes ( text );
        SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm = DES.Create ();
        symmetricAlgorithm.Key = new byte [8] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream ( encryptedBytes );
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream ( memoryStream, symmetricAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor (), CryptoStreamMode.Read );
        byte [] decryptedBytes = new byte [encryptedBytes.Length];
        cryptoStream.Read ( decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length );
        result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString ( decryptedBytes );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Encryption works but upon attempting to decrypt I receive this error :

`CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 0.`

Comment: The types/methods in `System.Text.Encoding` are for when you have an *arbitrary string* and want to convert that into a sequence of bytes, and for undoing such transformations. The output from encryption is an *arbitrary sequence of bytes* with no guarantee that those bytes can be interpreted as e.g. Unicode. Are you maybe looking for `Convert.ToBase64String` or similar?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Having attempted the change suggested my error code has changed to `CryptographicException: Bad PKCS7 padding. Invalid length 229.`

Comment: You seem to be not specifying an IV which is going to cause problems with your decrypting I think. Also you may want to either call `cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();` or `cryptoStream.Close();` to make sure the final block is properly flushed written to the output. I'm not sure why you are getting the Bad PKCS7 padding error though. When I try your methods in a test program with Base64 encoding of the binary data I'm not getting that... Perhaps update the question with a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will allow us to reproduce the error ourselves...

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your advice, however i have in fact found a solution, which I will be posting soon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I came up with required an overhaul of my code but works and is :

```
public static string EncryptString(this string text, string passPhrase)
{
    string result = null;
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        byte [] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ( m_InitVector );
        byte [] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ( text );
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes ( passPhrase, null );
        byte [] keyBytes = password.GetBytes ( m_Keysize / 8 );
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged ();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor ( keyBytes, initVectorBytes );
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream ();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream ( memoryStream, encryptor,  CryptoStreamMode.Write );
        cryptoStream.Write ( plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length );
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock ();
        byte [] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray ();
        memoryStream.Close ();
        cryptoStream.Close ();
        result = Convert.ToBase64String ( cipherTextBytes );
    }
    return result;
}
```

and

```
public static string DecryptString(this string text, string passPhrase)
{
    string result = null;
    if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty ( text ) )
    {
        byte [] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ( m_InitVector );
        byte [] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String ( text );
        PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes ( passPhrase, null );
        byte [] keyBytes = password.GetBytes ( m_Keysize / 8 );
        RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged ();
        symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor ( keyBytes, initVectorBytes );
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream ( cipherTextBytes );
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream ( memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read );
        byte [] plainTextBytes = new byte [cipherTextBytes.Length];
        int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read ( plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length );
        memoryStream.Close ();
        cryptoStream.Close ();
        result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString ( plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount );
    }
    return result;
}
```